# How can I get password from Firebase database and match with edittext?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am new in android studio and java as well

I created on firebasedatabase  codes and I want to code it as shown below

```
Class aclass {
String codeX= someedittext.toString();
String codeY= coderetrievedfromfirebase.toString();
if (codex=codey){do something};
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `.equals()` to compare `String`.

Comment: yes but the problem is I dont know how to retrieve that string from firebase

Comment: Have you read this ? https://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use **FirebaseAuth** to authenticate your email and password by using below code:-

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
```

updateUI:

```
private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user){
if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
    Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

    // Check if user's email is verified
    boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();

    // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
    // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
    // FirebaseUser.getIdToken() instead.
    String uid = user.getUid();
}
}
```

For more information you may go through [Google Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start)